# PHP if statement outputs number 1

Tags: php

Im working on a Wordpress site. This bit of PHP codes outputs what is in menu_community.php but also adds a number 1.  The number appears right where the code is, I need to remove this.

How can I avoid this? I have tried writing the code differently, but I cannot get what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate if someone could help me find out what is my flaw.

```
        <?php if (is_page(2381)|| is_page(5427) || is_page(5120) || is_page(4623) || is_page(4857)) {
           echo include("menu_community.php");
 } else {
    // This is not a community page
} ?>
```

also I have tried with:

```
        <?php if ( is_page(array(2381, 5427, 5120, 4623, 4857)) ) {
           echo include("menu_community.php");
 } else {
    // This is not a subpage
} ?>
```

Comment: because, you're echoing the include; *why?*

Comment: `echo include("menu_community.php");` need to be `include("menu_community.php");`. why to `echo` `include`?

Comment: from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-157) _Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1_

Comment: whatever's inside those files, then that's where you "echo" :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `echo`. You just need `include("menu_community.php");`